# topology of dual $k-$ linear space

Tags: general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, hopf-algebras

The problem arises when I was reading the book Hopf Algebra written by Eiichi Abe. I asked a qustion related to this question on this site [Topology of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416537/representative-bialgebras-of-semigroups).

In the book, a subspace is referred to a topological subspace and a $k$-linear subspace is just a linear subspace.

On page 70, there is an exercise :

Let $u:V\rightarrow W$ be a $k$-linear map and let $u^*:W^*\rightarrow V^*$ be its dual $k$-linear map. Then $u^*$ is a continuous function and the image of a closed subspace of $W^*$ is a closed subspace of $V^*$. Moreover, if we let $S$, $T$ be $k$- linear subspaces of $V$, $W$ respectively, then $$u^{*-1}(S^{\perp})=(u(S))^{\perp}, u^{*}(T^{\perp})=(u^{-1}(T))^{\perp}$$
My question is how to prove $u^{*}(T^{\perp})=(u^{-1}(T))^{\perp}$ and the image of a closed subspace of $W^*$ is a closed subspace of $V^*$.

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Comment: I assume $V, W$ are finite dimensional, right? Is $k$ arbitrary? What is the topology on $V^*$ then?

Comment: @freakish No, in general. $k$ is an arbitrary field.

Comment: The topology is called the finite topology. See Hopf Algebra An Introduction written by Sorin, page 10.

Comment: I don't have access to the book. Can you add the definition to your question?

Comment: As long as it is readable then I think yes.

Comment: My question is  in the last photo, exercise 1.2.18. Sorry to make it so long to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. I think it's not that trivial, so I post the answer. First, note that $V\subset V^{**}$ is a dense subset. Denote by $ X^{\perp(V^{**})}$ the orthogonal of $X$ in $V^{**}$. Then $V\cap X^{\perp(V^{**})}=X^{\perp}$. Denote by $(u^*(T^{\perp}))^{\perp(V^{**})}=R$, $(u^{-1}(T))^{\perp\perp(V^{**})}=S$ . By exercise 1.2.18(ii) (which is easy to prove), we have $V\cap R=V\cap S$ since $T^{\perp\perp}=T$ and $V\cap S=u^{-1}(T)$ by corollary. 1.2.8.  If we prove that $R=S$,then we are done since $R^{\perp}=u^*(T^\perp)$ and $S^{\perp}= (u^{-1}(T))^{\perp}$. Note that both $R$ and $S$ are closed in $V^{**}$ and $V$ is a dense subset. Then the closure of $V\cap R$ in $R$ is $R$. But $V\cap R=V\cap S\subset S$ is closed in $ R$. Thus we have $R=S$.